# Magento 1.7 - send email to customer after chanfing status to shipped

Tags: api, email, magento-1.7

In Magento 1.7, I would like to programatically trigger the sending of an email after programatically changing status to shipped.  In the code below, the status is changed but the email is not sent. Is there a bug in the API, or maybe I am using it wrong.

```
 function setShipOrder($orderID){

        // check if valid order number
        try{
            $order = $this->soapObject->call($this->sessionId, 'sales_order.info', $orderID);           
        }
        catch (SoapFault $e){
            output_error_xml(1600);         
        }

        // try to ship          
        try{
                $newShipmentId = $this->soapObject->call($this->sessionId, 'sales_order_shipment.create', array($orderID, array(), 'Order has been shipped', true, true));            
                $this->outputOrderSuccessXml("Your order" . $orderID . " was shipped" , $newShipmentId);

            }
            catch (SoapFault $e){                   
                ...
            }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to enable Email Notification for new shipments:

System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails -> Shipment